# Can I close the browser while Magento is reindexing?

Tags: reindex

While Magento is reindexing data, can I close the browser? Or does the browser still need to be open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can close it and it will be OK. if you re-open it and its still not done the status will be processing.

Comment: I wondered why it would sometimes say processing instead of reindexing. Thanks for your answer!